Golang Stomp Websocket Connection: Handling Heartbeats with Stomp Library
I'm creating a Stomp websocket client in Golang using . I've set up the connection with the following options:
    stomp.ConnOpt.HeartBeat(5*time.Second, 4*time.Second))

However, my websocket client is able to receive messages from the server but it looses connection with the server after x minutes, indicating the error readTimeout. When establishing the connection to the Stomp server, I have provided the optional HeartBeat values as mentioned above. My question is, does the Go Stomp library expect the client application to send heartbeat frame periodically, or will it send heartbeat to the server as per the heart beat options given in Connect ?
I'm uncertain whether I have to write code in my application to send heartbeat or if the library handles this internally. Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

maybe this is the problem
if you use go-stomp the parameters are first send and then receive
HeartBeat func(sendTimeout, recvTimeout time.Duration)
You have configured to send every 5 seconds and receive every 4, it should be the other way around, send every 4 seconds and expect to receive every 5 and make sure you have the same configuration on the server.
stomp.ConnOpt.HeartBeat(4*time.Second, 5*time.Second))


Despite following your advice, I still face the same error.
Considering a custom heartbeat checker, I have this drafted code like below:
func sendHeartbeat(conn *stomp.Conn) error {     heartbeatMsg := []byte("heartbeat")     msg, _ := json.Marshal(heartbeatMsg)     err := conn.Send("Destination", contentType, msg)     if err != nil { return err }     return nil }
I'm Unsure about the message content and destination path. Any guidance? Thanks!
